# Generate .chm file from the library

Tags: c#, .net, sandcastle, xml-documentation

I want to generate a '.chm' file from dll and xml files (XML Documentation). [Sandcastle Help file builder](https://shfb.codeplex.com/releases/view/121365) program does exactly what I need, but on some computers the file opens incorrectly.

This is what I want to get without having to install additional software
[image]

Some users get result such as
[image]

P.S. This is the same file

Can anyone faced with a similar problem?

Maybe you know a similar program to get the .chm file from XML documentation?

I hope very much for your help.

Thanks

Comment: CHM has not aged well, rather incompatible with security counter-measures.  The obvious google query is "chm file getting blank page", the obvious answer is "right-click the file and click Unblock".

Comment: This usually happens when the file is downloaded and not trusted on the machine, yet. Often editing this in the properties helps; also moving it to a less restricted directory can help.

Comment: Another possibility is that sometimes the CHM doesn't work from a network drive but works OK if copied to the local hard disk.

Comment: "Maybe you know a similar program to get the .chm file from XML documentation?" What the above three comments are implying are that there are intrinsic problems with the .chm file support in Windows, so switching to a different .chm generating program might not help. If it's not absolutely necessary that it is .chm, maybe switching to a completely different file type would be the best solution.

Comment: Hans Passant, thank you very much.

Comment: Off-topic - but if you want to notify Hans Passant you should type @h and then pick his name from the little popup. That way he gets a notification, otherwise he'll only see your comment if he happens to come back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RenniePet's answer worked for me. Couple other things that I learned (SandCastle via Visual Studio 2015):

1) In properties/Build of your SandCastle project, make sure that your framework version matches the version of the project(s) you are documenting.

2) In properties/Build of your Sandcastle project, try HTML/ASP.NET as your file format. Verify whether or not a different file format outputs the comments successfully.

3) In properties/Build of the project you are documenting, ensure "XML documentation file" is checked.